# cmake using wrong library: native instead of macports

Tags: macos, cmake

I want to compile a project, but it keeps failing because make is somehow using the wrong library. It is clearly installed, but I have no idea why make is preferring the outdated local library.

```
▶ pkg-config --cflags ldap
-I/opt/local/include

▶ pkg-config --libs ldap
-L/opt/local/lib -lldap -llber
```

Warning:

```
./src/ov_vocs_db_persistance.c:1083:5: warning: 'ldap_unbind_ext_s' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - use OpenDirectory Framework [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ldap_unbind_ext_s(ld, NULL, NULL);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ldap.h:1956:1: note: 'ldap_unbind_ext_s' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
ldap_unbind_ext_s LDAP_P((
^
./src/ov_vocs_db_persistance.c:1094:13: warning: 'ldap_unbind_ext_s' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - use OpenDirectory Framework [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    if (ld) ldap_unbind_ext_s(ld, NULL, NULL);
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ldap.h:1956:1: note: 'ldap_unbind_ext_s' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
ldap_unbind_ext_s LDAP_P((
^
```

How do I get make to use the library I installed with macports?

Comment: Probably, some component in your project adds `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include` directory as include one. Hard to guess without viewing the code of the project.

Comment: is there a way to force make to import this the pkg-config lib and not use the system lib?

Comment: If a source file uses a header file which exists only under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`, then that directory should be added to the **list of include directories**. And once this directory is included, no one can prevent the compiler to search **other headers** in that directory. Well, you may place directory `/opt/local/include` at the beginning of the list, so if a compiler finds `ldap.h` in it, then it won't search that header in following directories. But approach with directories *ordering* is not scaled well and is not supported by CMake.

Comment: In short, the only reliable way for force CMake (or other build tool) to use some library under specific installation prefix is to use all libraries under that prefix. Do you have under `/opt/local/` **all libraries** needed for your project? If yes, then there is a chance to build such project correctly.